# php why does 0 == 'somestr' evaluate to true

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
echo ( $arr['process_refunds'] == 'storecredit' ) ? 'true' : 'false'
```

The value in `$arr['process_refunds']` is `0` type `int(0)`.

It tried in `php -a` and it turns out that if we compare any string with 
`==` with `int(0)` it evaluates to `true`.

Why is that?

Comment: because `intval("anystring")` === `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's pretty obvious that the loose comparison is not returning expected values. You can see the comparison table here (2nd table)

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

you can see that this is **expected behaviour**. This is because php converts the string `"php"` or `"somestr"`to a match the number type, making it equal to 0, before making the assessment.

[image]

Unless there are other types/conditions you're looking to match with a loose comparison, to get around this, you should use `===` that will assure you have the matching type.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `==` is a loosely-typed comparison operator. It is converting your string to a number, therefore it evaluates to true. Try using `===`.

Your string is getting converted to a zero because it starts with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
php -r "echo ( $arr['process_refunds'] == 'storecredit' ) ? 'true' : 'false';"
```

prints:

```
false
```

It is obvious because `$arr` is undefined. But if it has value 0 then

```
php -r "echo ( 0 == 'storecredit' ) ? 'true' : 'false';"
```

prints:

```
true
```

because both `0` and `'storecredit'` are converted to integers.

Value of (int) 'storecredit' is 0 because of it does not contain any number on start of string. For example string '4ss' would be converted to 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need no use === because in that way you compare both values are the same type and the same content; example

```
echo 0 === 'somstr'; // returns false

echo 0 == 'somstr';  //return true
```